# AllowEncodedSlashes has no affect

Tags: apache, jenkins, httpd.conf

I'm using Apache 2.4 as a reverse proxy towards my Jenkins server. I've followed [the documentation at their website](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Apache) to configure Apache correctly, but the internal test for escaped urls fails. This means that if I were to access e.g. https://example.com/jenkins/%2Fjenkins%2F, I would get a 404 from Apache (not Jenkins) saying that https://example.com/jenkins//jenkins/ does not exist. However, I can see that the url is escaped in the logs, but it still returns 404 without even forwarding the call to Jenkins.

The reverse proxy is set up at the end of httpd.conf:

```
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
ProxyRequests off

<Location /jenkins>
  ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/jenkins nocanon
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/jenkins
  SSLRequireSSL

  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
  RequestHeader set Host "example.com"
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-For ""
  Header edit Location ^http://example.com/jenkins/ https://example.com/jenkins/
</Location>
```

How can I make Apache properly forward urls with %2F inside them?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?